# TypesError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, pygame, tuples, typeerror

I'm trying to make a hangman but I get the following error:

[image]

I'm trying to get it to return the x-coordinate of pos_.

code snippet including the error:

```
        def DrawLetter(IndexNumber):
        if letterlist[x-1] == "g":
            pos_ = (AdjustMe + (27 * int(IndexNumber), 226))
        else:
            pos_ = (AdjustMe + (27 * int(IndexNumber), 230))
        screen.blit(letter, pos_)
        screen.blit(BottomDashes, (0, 256))
        lettersguessed.append(letterlist[x-1])
        print(x)
        if LTGL == lettersguessed:
            print("you won")
            running = False

    while x < len(letterlist):
        duplicates = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(word).items() if count > 1]
        if letterlist.count(letterlist[x-1]) > 1:
            for y in duplicates:
                DuplicatesList = [i for i, e in enumerate(word) if e == y]
            IndexNumber = list(DuplicatesList)
            print(IndexNumber)
            DrawLetter(IndexNumber)
        else:
            IndexNumber = LTGL.index(letterlist[x - 1])
            DrawLetter(IndexNumber)
        x += 1
```

entire code:

```
    from random_word import RandomWords
r = RandomWords()
import pygame
import sys
import collections

def main():
    pygame.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    size = [256, 356]
    white = [255, 255, 255]
    black = [0, 0, 0]

    word = "{0}".format(r.get_random_word(hasDictionaryDef="true", minLength=4, maxLength=8))
    ListToGuess = list(word)
    LTGL = ListToGuess
    print(ListToGuess)

    pygame.display.set_caption('Hang man')
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 28)

    def DisplayLetter(LTGL, letterlist, lettersguessed):
        if len(LTGL) == 4:
            AdjustMe = 78
        if len(LTGL) == 5:
            AdjustMe = 63
        if len(LTGL) == 6:
            AdjustMe = 53
        if len(LTGL) == 7:
            AdjustMe = 37
        if len(LTGL) == 8:
            AdjustMe = 25
        x = 0
        letter = font.render(letterlist[x-1], True, black, white)

        def DrawLetter(IndexNumber):
            if letterlist[x-1] == "g":
                pos_ = (AdjustMe + (27 * int(IndexNumber), 226))
            else:
                pos_ = (AdjustMe + (27 * int(IndexNumber), 230))
            screen.blit(letter, pos_)
            screen.blit(BottomDashes, (0, 256))
            lettersguessed.append(letterlist[x-1])
            print(x)
            if LTGL == lettersguessed:
                print("you won")
                running = False

        while x < len(letterlist):
            duplicates = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(word).items() if count > 1]
            if letterlist.count(letterlist[x-1]) > 1:
                for y in duplicates:
                    DuplicatesList = [i for i, e in enumerate(word) if e == y]
                IndexNumber = list(DuplicatesList)
                print(IndexNumber)
                DrawLetter(IndexNumber)
            else:
                IndexNumber = LTGL.index(letterlist[x - 1])
                DrawLetter(IndexNumber)
            x += 1

    YouLost = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Wit\Desktop\Programming shit\img\Hangman\Youlost.png')
    WhitePng = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Wit\Desktop\Programming shit\img\Hangman\white100px.png')
    BottomDashes = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Wit\Desktop\Programming shit\img\Hangman\Dashes{0}.png'.format(len(ListToGuess)))

    def HangmanDrawImg(Mistakes):
        HangmanImg = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Wit\Desktop\Programming shit\img\Hangman\Hangman{0}.png'.format(Mistakes))
        screen.blit(HangmanImg, (30, -50))

    screen.fill(white)
    button = pygame.Rect(103, 296, 50, 50)  # creates a rect object
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255, 0, 0], button)  # draw button
    screen.blit(BottomDashes, (0, 256))
    pygame.display.flip()

    lettersguessed = []
    running = True
    Mistakes = 0

    while running is True:
        try:
            letter = ""
            if Mistakes == 9:
                screen.blit(WhitePng, (0, 259))
                screen.blit(YouLost, (20, 286))
                pygame.display.flip()
                break
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
                    return running
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    mouse_pos = event.pos
                    if button.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                        Mistakes += 1
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    current_text = letter
                    letter += event.unicode
            if current_text == letter:
                pass
            elif letter not in ListToGuess:
                Mistakes += 1
            elif letter in ListToGuess:
                RunMe = True
                letterlist = []
                while RunMe:
                    lettercount = ListToGuess.count(letter)
                    if lettercount > 0:
                        letterlist.append(letter)
                        letterfind = ListToGuess.index(letter)
                        ListToGuess.pop(letterfind)
                    if lettercount == 0:
                        RunMe = False
                        LTGL.insert(letterfind, letter)
                        DisplayLetter(LTGL, letterlist, lettersguessed)
            HangmanDrawImg(Mistakes)
            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(50)
        except UnboundLocalError:
            pass
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Bonus points if someone can point out some code that doesn't follow PEP8.
Also, notice that this is far from finished, so if there is some code as comments, I'll remove them later.

Comment: pos_ is a position for the letters that need to be printed in the pygame. 226 is the y coordinate, thus 27 * int(IndexNumber) is the x coordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This here:

```
pos_ = (AdjustMe + (27 * int(IndexNumber), 226))
```

is the same as:

```
pos_ = (int + (int * int, int)) ->
       (int + tuple)
```

---

*How is python supposed to add that integer to that tuple?*

**Here is the corrected way:**

```
if letterlist[x-1] == "g":
    pos_ = (27 * int(IndexNumber) + AdjustMe, 226 + AdjustMe)
else:
    pos_ = (27 * int(IndexNumber) + AdjustMe, 230 + AdjustMe)
```